# How can we use Genymotion with Eclipse and Appium

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium, genymotion

**REQUIREMENT** - Need to connect a emulator with my Appium code. As my normal emulator takes even 2 days to open the menu screen, I have been trying to use "GENYMOTION" which is fast.

**PROBLEM** - After starting a virtual device, Looking in cmd prompt for list of devices keying "adb devices". I have my virtual device name listed as "192.168.175.101:5555". How can I connect the virual device? How can I install my app??

**HELP NEEDED** - Now how should I make use of Genymotion virtual device to work for my Appium automated test.
Should I make changes in the Android settings of Appium? If so explain.
Should I change the name of device in code?`capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","192.168.175.101:5555");`

Comment: Can we please have a selected answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes change port number in android settings and in code also both the port number should be the same i.e android settings and code port numbers.

To install the required app in connected devices follow the below points

1.Open command prompt.
2.type adb install space and then drag the apk file from the saved folder and click enter.
3.wait some time app will install and responds with success message

Answer (score 2):

At maximum that you need to do is mention the device name as set in GenyMotion by you. The capability deviceName as used in android is currently ignored, you can refer the documents on [appium.io](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#the---default-capabilities-flag)

> **deviceName**     -    The kind of mobile device or emulator to use  iPhone
>   Simulator, iPad Simulator, iPhone Retina 4-inch, Android Emulator,
>   Galaxy S4, etc…. On iOS, this should be one of the valid devices
>   returned by instruments with instruments -s devices. On Android this
>   capability is currently ignored.

So you can continue using the line of code :

```
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","192.168.175.101:5555"); //you can provide the name as "TestDevice", "Emulator" etc..
```

Irrespective of what name you provide, appium uses the *first available device* from the list of adb devices on your machine.

Also on your appium server GUI, you might want to **uncheck** the emulator option if you are using GenyMotion, as appium would treat it as a real device connected for automation.

Comment: Thanks for the help and I need help in installing a apk in the virtual device. The virtual device which is in Genymotion.

Comment: @Rick : the installation continues as you find in any sample code over the internet

Comment: @Rick : i hope the answer helps.

Comment: Yes, Simply dragging and putting in the emulator screen installs the .apk file

Comment: @Rick : true it does :)